# Image segmentation based on texture (Unsupervised) in Python-OpenCV

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, opencv, numpy

I want to segment the two regions in the images, based on unsupervised methods. 
I have tried kmeans clustering, edge detection algorithms, frequency analysis etc. But not able to do it. Anyone with suggestions to get the desired results. Here is my image. 
[image: Original Image]
And here is the background removed image
[image]

Comment: Search for matting something like this: http://mpac.ee.ntu.edu.tw/personal/sutony/public_html/vfx_matting/index.html It takes trimap mask, and gives you accurate alpha mask.